# How to force JSON when using FreeRADIUS REST Module

Tags: freeradius

I have compiled in JSON support to FreeRADIUS 3.0.2 however I note that if I configure authorisation to use POST it is sending RADIUS attributes encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Is there a way to force this to POST JSON content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you compile with `json-c` and set the `<section>.body` config item to `json`.

Comment: OK thanks, figured it out, was missing body = "json" in my authorize section in the rest configuration file